# How to share variables among different php scripts embedded in the same html file?

Tags: php, html, json, variables

So I have a HTML document with php embedded (`.php` file). When loading the page, I issue a request to a GET service of mine, and retrieve the information I want. But that information has to be split (it's a JSON) and displayed in different parts of the final HTML document. Is there any way to make that info be available along the different `<?php ... ?>` parts of the document so I don't have to be printing the whole static HTML structure? I just intend to echo what I have to retrieve from the JSON, but apparently there is no straightforward way to keep variables alive among different `<?php ... ?>`.

As a workaround, I'm gonna use `$_SESSION` variables by now, but it looks like a total overkill to me.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `global` varaibles. So that it is available is all the scripts. define the varaible as `global` and assign the json value to it.

Refer for more details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: just realized I didn't really need to use the global statement. Variables are shared across multiple php invocations in the same php file. I was simply not defining the variable due to it being inside an if never executed... I'm sorry